# Квадратный корень в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

как сделать корень в Котлине? Знаю, что надо использовать sqrt, но как?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например, так:

```
var y = sqrt(x)
```

Если `x` - integer, то предварительно конвертировать в Double или Float:

```
var y = sqrt(x.toDouble())
```

Перед этим функцию sqrt() нужно импортировать:

```
import kotlin.math.sqrt
```